# how to use GMM on sentinel2 image?

Tags: python-3.x, gmm, sentinel2

** I am working on sentinel images and when I apply the GMM on those images I got an error while reshaping the image I tried this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture as GMM
samples = 59
lines   = 104
w=10
h=10
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
g = open("C:/Users/oussa/Desktop/masques/01janvier/bande_04", 'rb')
im = np.fromfile(g, np.uint16,(samples * lines))
g.close()
im2 = np.reshape(im, (samples, lines), order="F")
print(im2)
gmm_model=GMM(n_components=59).fit(im2)
gmm_labels=gmm_model.predict(im2)
print(gmm_labels)
print(im2.shape)
original_shape=im2.shape
segmented_image=gmm_labels.reshape(original_shape[0],original_shape[1])
plt.imshow(segmented_image,cmap='gray',vmin=0,vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

**[this is the image that I am working on(spectral band)](https://gofile.io/?c=Eab7GO)

Comment: What is the error? Please include it in your question.